# Python data frame, for loop and type casts

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, casting

I have a data frame with several columns. My goal is to manipulate the last column in a certain way. Until now the last column has the type string. I need help by building a for loop that walks through the last column and removes the last two chars and then typecasts it into a float.

An example for an entry in the last column is "1234.5678;;". I want it to look like 1234.5678 and that for every entry for the last column.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure of what exactly you are asking, are you asking for how you can manipulate a string to remove the last two chars? Or are you asking for how you access (and edit/change) a data frame? If so are you using pandas?

Clarifying that may help other people help you with your issue more effectively.

In python, given any string, you can cut off the last two characters like this:

```
string=string[:-2]
```

I assume that the variable string holds your string you want.

For the future it would be greatly appreciated if you were to explain your issue in more detail, explain what it is you want to do and where you need help and to overall put in more effort into your question, a spelling mistake in the title is not a good look optics wise.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using a pandas DataFrame, you can do it like this:

```
w.iloc[:][w.columns.size-1]=w.iloc[:][w.columns.size-1].str.replace(";;","")
```

`w` is your DataFrame. This line will replace all the `;` in the column. I assume that the last two characters always follow the same pattern. This will obviously not work if the last two characters follow a not known pattern.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was able to implement the for-loop. I still have a little question left. The header of the last column has the two ";;" as well at the end that I want to remove. How can I do this, so that the name will be permanent and not just a copy?

Comment: Have a look at [pandas.DataFrame.rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html). There examples how you can rename the column. For what do you use a `for`-loop?

Comment: I was using the loop for going through the column of the data frame to delete the two ";;" after each entry.